# Moving UIView up when UITextField is selected

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield

I am trying to programatically create some text fields. They appear at the bottom of the screen and when selected the keyboard covers them. I need to move the view up when the textfield is selected.

Here is my code for the View:

Header:

```
@interface MESLoginViewController : UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
}
```

Imp View file:

```
// Create sub view for Logo
    UIView *logoView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,280)];
    [logoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    logoView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // Create sub view for fields
    UIView *fieldView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, logoView.bounds.size.height, 320, 200)];
    [fieldView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    fieldView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

    // Setting up the text fields
    // Username field
    usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)];
    usernameField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    usernameField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    usernameField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    usernameField.placeholder = @"Username";
    usernameField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    usernameField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    usernameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    usernameField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
    usernameField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    usernameField.delegate = self;

    // Password field
    UITextField *passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, (usernameField.bounds.size.height + 30), 300, 40)];
    passwordField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    passwordField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    passwordField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    passwordField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    passwordField.placeholder = @"Password";
    passwordField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    passwordField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    passwordField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    passwordField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
    passwordField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    passwordField.delegate = self;

    // Add fields/button to fieldView
    [fieldView addSubview:usernameField];
    [fieldView addSubview:passwordField];

    // Add subviews to main view
    [self.view addSubview:logoView];
    [self.view addSubview:fieldView];
```

I have added this method for moving the view but cannot correctly work out the last part:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");
    //If we begin editing on the text field we need to move it up to make sure we can still
    //see it when the keyboard is visible.
    //I am adding an animation to make this look better
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animate Text Field Up" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    usernameField.frame = CGRectMake(usernameField.frame.origin.x,
                                        -200,
                                        usernameField.frame.size.width,
                                        usernameField.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

What I am actually looking for is to completely shift the view, or possible change it to a scrollable area above. Although I do implement another method after touch to endEditing.

It seems if I move one field I would have to complete code to move all... How can I just move the view (complete view)?

Also what is needed for the view to return to normal state in the method textFieldDidEndEditing|textFieldShouldEndEditing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you animate after the keyboard becomes selected - animate the entire view instead.

First declare the UIView variable to make it accessible:

```
@interface MESLoginViewController : UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> 
{ 
IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField; 
UIView *fieldView; 
}
```

Then create this view in your implementation

```
 // Create sub view for Logo
UIView *logoView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,280)];
[logoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
logoView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

// Create sub view for fields
fieldView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, logoView.bounds.size.height, 320, 200)];
[fieldView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
fieldView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

// Setting up the text fields
// Username field
usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)];
usernameField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
usernameField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
usernameField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
usernameField.placeholder = @"Username";
usernameField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
usernameField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
usernameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
usernameField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
usernameField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
usernameField.delegate = self;

// Password field
UITextField *passwordField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, (usernameField.bounds.size.height + 30), 300, 40)];
passwordField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
passwordField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
passwordField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
passwordField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
passwordField.placeholder = @"Password";
passwordField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
passwordField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
passwordField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
passwordField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
passwordField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
passwordField.delegate = self;

// Add fields/button to fieldView
[fieldView addSubview:usernameField];
[fieldView addSubview:passwordField];

// Add subviews to main view
[self.view addSubview:logoView];
[self.view addSubview:fieldView];
```

Then animate the fieldView instead:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");
//If we begin editing on the text field we need to move it up to make sure we can still
//see it when the keyboard is visible.
//I am adding an animation to make this look better
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Animate Text Field Up" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

fieldView.frame = CGRectMake(fieldView.frame.origin.x,
                                    -200,
                                    fieldView.frame.size.width,
                                    fieldView.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

As all the text fields are subviews of fieldView - they will animate with it. That should sort it!

Comment: Thanks, but then the logo view would not shift as well, so if the view did not cover the logo view you would see an overlap. Is there anyway to move the whole view. Should I create another variable that is the whole view and update the origin.y on this instead?

Comment: Oh my mistake - easy fix. Use self.view.frame instead of fieldView.frame in the textFieldDidBeginEditing method and that'll move the entire view.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a local variable `usernameField` in a method my friend. That is the compiler error.

Comment: Ok I have updated the code, I will update the question. I can now make the field move too, but I would actually like the whole view as opposed to changing the individual frame for the text field only...

Comment: You can shift the all views you want one by one or whole view itself. You have the code that does the shifting for the usernameField, why not use it for other views?

Comment: I am unsure how to... How do I move the whole view, including sub views is the actual question.

Comment: Is moving usernamefield and passwordfield enough for you? If so, you could move `fieldView` up just like you did it for usernamefield.

Comment: I would like to move the whole view, but do not know how... this is the answer i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct - you actually want to shift the "fieldView" - because the two UITextFields are Subviews of this view.

The reason you're throwing that error is because the variable isn't accessible in that method - you need to declare an instance variable in your header file.

Comment: Correct. I have updated the question with corrected code, but still unsure how to move the entire view.

Comment: You can either shift the fieldView - which contains your usernameField and passwordField - or the entire View (self.view)

Comment: I am unsure how to... How do I move the whole view, including sub views is the actual question.

Comment: If you shift the main view - all subviews will shift with it.

Comment: I want to shift the whole view (main view). As yet I do not have an answer as to how to do this...

Comment: Declare the fieldView in the header: @interface MESLoginViewController : UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;  UIView *fieldView;
}

Comment: I understand this, but it is not answering my question. I am asking how to move the entire view, ignore the field sub view for now. How do I move the whole view textFieldDidBeginEditing method is the question. Explaining how to create a subview in the View Controller header file does not answer the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following code in your .h and .m files it works fine for me.

-------.h-----

```
CGFloat animatedDistance;
```

--------.m----------

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator =
    midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =
    (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        //animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction) textFieldReturn:(id)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I've got the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809290/how-to-move-the-focussed-text-field-to-the-middle-of-the-view-after-keyboard-pop)